# How can I click OK with Apple Script?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to select OK with the popup for scaling the screen with Apple script.

Does anyone know what I can add to this script to allow me to click OK?

Apple Script:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "Built-in Retina Display"
    click radio button "Scaled" of radio group 1 of tab group 1
    click radio button 1 of radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1

    (* Trying to click the ok button here *)
    delay 1
    click ((pop up buttons of sheet 1 of window 1) whose description is "OK")

end tell

quit application "System Preferences"
```

[image]

Or also rather does anyone know a trusted **application that can graphically print out the labels** of the UI when I visit them on my screen so I will know what to use when I say: "tell **UIName**"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Press <kbd>Return</kbd>

Since you're using *System Events* anyway, and the button in question is selected by default (indicated by being highlighted in blue), just make sure that the preference pane is in focus and use *System Events* to hit the <kbd>return</kbd> key:

```
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
```

It's quick, simple, and saves the hassle of identifying UI elements within the hierarchy.  The drawback is that the preference pane has tone in focus, and if it loses focus before it receives the keystroke, the rest of the script will fail.

#### Solution 2: The One You Asked For

Regarding identification of UI elements within the GUI objects hierarchy, you got the class of the button in question wrong as well as its description.

The "OK" button is referenced like so:

```
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" ¬
        to get button "OK" of sheet 1 of window "Built-in Retina Display"
```

(`window 1` is also fine).  You *can* use the `whose` filter to target it instead, which would be done like this (via *System Events* and the *System Preferences* process):

```
    get buttons of sheet 1 of window 1 whose name is "OK"
```

but all this does is ask AppleScript to search for a button whose name we know, then annoyingly give the result back to us as a list (the list structure can be flattened by requesting the `first button of sheet 1...`).

However, we do know its name and that there's only one of it, so we can reference it by name directly.

As a side-bar, if you quickly run this command:

```
    get the properties of button "OK" of sheet 1 of window "Built-in Retina Display"
```

you'll be able to see that its description is merely "button", which isn't what you had hoped.  Now run this command:

```
    get the actions of button "OK" of sheet 1 of window "Built-in Retina Display"
```

which reveals it has one action available, `AXPress` (this is equivalent to a mouse click).

Therefore, finally, the way to click the button in a more satisfactory way than hitting the return key looks like this:

```
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" ¬
        to tell button "OK" of sheet 1 of window "Built-in Retina Display" ¬
            to perform action "AXPress"
```

---

For exploring the GUI objects on the screen, I occasionally use the *Accessibility Inspector* that comes with Apple's *XCode*.  It's vaguely useful, although inconveniently annoying with some of the discrepancies between the names by which it references objects and the names by which AppleScript does (they're also really subtle discrepancies, but enough to stop your script from working and send you into a frenzy for weeks).

So, actually, I just explore it programmatically myself in *Script Editor*.

What I did to solve your issue was to bring up the pane and the dialog box in question, then systematically tell the *System Preferences* process to `get UI elements`; then `get buttons of UI elements`; then `get buttons of UI elements of UI elements`, and stop when I saw a pair of buttons returned called "OK" and "Cancel".  It can be pain-staking, but it'll get you the correct reference.

There are other ways too, but I would be moving beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for this answer it's really informative and helpful. Btw how can I set focus on System Preferences, my service is activated from Finder when it is in focus. I still can't get the enter keystroke to hit the "OK" button because Finder is still in focus.

Comment: You're welcome @Jonathan002.  To change focus from *Finder* to *System Preferences*, I believe you can `tell application "System Preferences" to activate`.